# Using tcolorbox, the first letter in the body disappears. What can be done?

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm using tcolorbox but the first letter of the body text always disappears.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage[english]{babel}         
\usepackage{tcolorbox}              
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}                
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myprop}{Proposition}{colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\begin{document}
\begin{myprop}{Proposition name}
Just some text.
\end{myprop}
\end{document}
```

The previous code results in: [image]

It's a fairly easy to just type the first letter twice (which yields the desired effect) but if there is a more legitimate solution I'm interested in hearing it.

Edit: Arun Debray is correct. The environment takes two arguments and should be written as `\begin{myprop}{Proposition name}{label}`. Problem solved!

Comment: Any environment defined by `\newtcbtheorem` takes two arguments: the proposition name and the proposition label. Since you didn't specify the label, the parser gobbles the first letter as the label. Try using `\begin{myprop}{Prop. name}{prop_label}`.

Comment: @ArunDebray: Write up an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any environment defined by `\newtcbtheorem` takes two arguments: the proposition name and the proposition label. Since you didn't specify the label, the parser gobbles the first letter as the label. Try using `\begin{myprop}{Prop. name}{prop_label}`.

Source: [`tcolorbox` documentation](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=361).

Comment: Great! Holds also for any environment where some arguments are missing.